# Merge two data into one to produce a new table - Javascript/ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data in the format as 'SectionText' mentioned below and i could build a table based on that data. But now for comparision purpose, i have another data as 'SectionTextTwo' in same format as the first but now i need to merge both the data into one table as shown below. I am confused as to how to merge or combine both the data into one and show it as a table. Any inputs would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
 SectionText = Node\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\n172.22.1.91\t30.4549\t30.5486\n172.22.1.92\t30.736\t30.5485\n


  var sectionRows = sectionText.split("\n");
  {sectionRows.map((currRow) => {
                    if (currRow.length > 0) {
                      var fields = currRow.split("\t");

                        return (
                            <TableRow>
                            {fields.map((currField) => {
                                return (
                                    <td>{currField}</td>
                                )
                            })}
                            </TableRow>
                        )

                    }
                })}


Node        MB-s (rec)  MB-s (sent)
172.22.1.91 30.4549     30.5486
172.22.1.92 30.736      30.5485


SectionTextTwo = Node\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\n172.22.1.91\t30.4549\t30.5486\n172.22.1.92\t30.736\t30.5485\n

Required table : 

Node        MB-s (rec)     MB-s (sent) Node          MB-s (rec)     MB-s (sent)
172.22.1.91  30.4549        30.5486    172.22.1.91    30.4549       30.5486
172.22.1.92   30.736        30.5485    172.22.1.92    30.736        30.5485
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I completely understood the problem in hand. But I guess that you can create a component to build the table, something like: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/69404/

```
// Table component
const buildRow = (row) => (
  <tr>{row.map((item) => <td>{item}</td>)}</tr>
);

const Table = ({ items }) => (
  <table>{items.map(buildRow)}</table>
);


// Usage
const SectionText = "Node\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\n172.22.1.91\t30.4549\t30.5486\n172.22.1.92\t30.736\t30.5485\n";
const SectionTextTwo = "Node\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\n172.22.1.91\t30.4549\t30.5486\n172.22.1.92\t30.736\t30.5485\n";

const sectionRows = SectionText.split("\n").map(row => row.split('\t'));
const sectionRowsTwo = SectionTextTwo.split("\n").map(row => row.split('\t'));

// As separate tables
ReactDOM.render(
  <div><Table items={sectionRows} /> <br/> <Table items={sectionRowsTwo} /> </div>,
  document.getElementById('container_1')
);

// As a single table
const sectionRowsMerged = sectionRows.concat(sectionRowsTwo.slice(1, sectionRowsTwo.length));
ReactDOM.render(
  <Table items={sectionRowsMerged} />,
  document.getElementById('container_2')
);
```

Basically first you would create a component that will abstract away from the logic of building the array and simply focus on the rendering of the data. Then you can use it to passing the formatted data.

If you want two tables, you just render that component twice. If you want a single table, you merge the arrays except the first row and call your Table component.

Comment: I want a single table with 6 rows - two side by side. I am not sure if you got that one from the example i gave above.

Comment: I guess that would be two tables, but then you use CSS to set them side by side. Check: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/69405/

Comment: I need to concat the two data into one data and one table - i need it so i can compare the data for reporting. I am sorry but i dont need two tables. I am finding a way to combine that data and show it as a table.

Comment: is it something you can help! I tried doing it but couldnt get the desired output

Comment: It's easier if you draw a mock-up of the expected result